# Does Android Market Accept app using WebViewClient?

Tags: android

I developing a web icon application.I used the below code to launch my url

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.myurl.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);

Does Android Market accept this type of application?

Comment: There are no restrictions on what the android market accepts and there is no review process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is acceptable. No restrictions on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are absolutely no restrictions on what you use in your application.

You code the app and launch it.

You just don't have to write a malicious code that steals user-data, else ur app will be killed after sometime, if Google guys find it out.